# Xamarin Forms Android Iframe Navigating Event not firing

Tags: xamarin, iframe, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-webview

I use the Navigating event of my WebView to treat some urls in a special way. If the web page has an iframe, the navigating event in Android is unfortunately not fired (iOS works fine).

Do you have an idea how to solve this problem?

Until now I found a similiar unanswered question in the [Xamarin Forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/114585/webview-navigating-event-for-iframe-in-android).

Comment: For this issue, try to create a custom webview renderer to fix the navigating event. The `WebviewRenderer` class provide the `ElementController.SendNavigating()` method which could help you to add the feature. Try to get the **WebNavigatedEventArgs** in the custom `WebViewClient` class, then set the event args to the custom webview renderer. Similar issue you can refer to: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/140516/webview-navigating-event-not-working

Comment: @y3z1 Could you provide a little more information? Even after adding the ElementController.SendNavigating, the navigating event is still not reflected for me.

Comment: @methus Were you able to get this working?

Comment: @pree I did not find a solution for this until now

Comment: @y3z1 were you able to find any solution for this at all